# Plus / Minus product with button

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I write a code in order to simulate "shopping cart", by adding / removing product using "+" "-" button, the issue that the code works fine but only to one product and i want the code to works for all the products.

Here the code :

```js
const minusButton = document.querySelector('.minus-btn');
const plusButton = document.querySelector('.plus-btn');
const inputField = document.querySelector('.input-btn');

minusButton.addEventListener('click', function minusProduct() {
  const currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
  if (currentValue > 0) {
    inputField.value = currentValue - 1;
  } else currentValue = 0
});

plusButton.addEventListener('click', function plusProduct() {
  const currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
  inputField.value = currentValue + 1;
});
```

```html
<!-- Product #1 -->
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button" id="plus"><img src="plus.svg" alt="" /></button>
  <input type="text" value="0" id="input" />
  <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button" id="minus"><img src="minus.svg" alt="" /></button>
</div>

<!-- Product #2 -->
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button" id="plus"><img src="plus.svg" alt="" /></button>
  <input type="text" value="0" id="input" />
  <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button" id="minus"><img src="minus.svg" alt="" /></button>
</div>

<!-- Product #3 -->
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button" id="plus"><img src="plus.svg" alt="" /></button>
  <input type="text" value="0" id="input" />
  <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button" id="minus"><img src="minus.svg" alt="" /></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: sry i added it now

Comment: Hi. Why don't you use JQuery? and your code (sorry to say but) it's a mess... I wolud recommend to just call a function on click with the item id as a parameter, and that's it...

Comment: it's kind of training project using js so i have to use only js code in order to achieve it

Comment: @AriWaisberg Why use a 90 kB library for something that can better be achieved without any external dependency?

Comment: @connexo if you can achieve everything faster it worth the 90kb...

Comment: @AriWaisberg no it is not, and the code is not really a mess. it just had bad formatting.

Comment: @connexo well... it's your opinion... i checked and it's 70kb (the slim version) and i rather use a lib to do it faster and easier, today 70kb its nothing and most browser have a copy cached locally... so... if you want to reinvent the wheel it's up to you... happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do what your code does for each `.quantity` group.

But there are a couple of errors in your html

- you try to access the `.input-btn` which is not applied to any element
- you try to set `currentValue` to 0 after declaring a `const` when you should try to set the input field to 0
- you are using the same `id` for the button/inputs of each `.quantity` group which is invalid.

so

```js
const quantities = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity');

[...quantities].forEach(function(quantity) {
  const minusButton = quantity.querySelector('.minus-btn');
  const plusButton = quantity.querySelector('.plus-btn');
  const inputField = quantity.querySelector('.input-btn');

  minusButton.addEventListener('click', function minusProduct() {
    const currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
    if (currentValue > 0) {
      inputField.value = currentValue - 1;
    } else inputField.value = 0
  });

  plusButton.addEventListener('click', function plusProduct() {
    const currentValue = Number(inputField.value);
    inputField.value = currentValue + 1;
  });

});
```

```html
<!-- Product #1 -->
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="plus.svg" alt="" /></button>
  <input type="text" value="0" class="input-btn" />
  <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="minus.svg" alt="" /></button>
</div>

<!-- Product #2 -->
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="plus.svg" alt="" /></button>
  <input type="text" value="0" class="input-btn" />
  <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="minus.svg" alt="" /></button>
</div>

<!-- Product #3 -->
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="plus.svg" alt="" /></button>
  <input type="text" value="0" class="input-btn" />
  <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button"><img src="minus.svg" alt="" /></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for all the great job and all your recommandations. <3 <3 <3

Comment: Good solution, but it might be worth pointing out that there is browsers where `NodeList` does not support `forEach`.

Comment: @connexo fair point, updated code to use an array instead.

Comment: `for (const quantity of quantities)` works in IE 11 with no polyfill and no Babeling needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `querySelector` only returns the first match. Instead, you want all the matches and iterate over that list, adding click listeners to each of them. Use `querySelectorAll` to find the elements, then iterate over it using a simple `for`-loop:

```js
const minusButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.minus-btn');
const plusButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.plus-btn');
const inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity input');

for (let i = 0; i < minusButtons.length; i++) {
  minusButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function minusProduct() {
    if (inputFields[i].value) {
      inputFields[i].value--;
    }
  });
}
for (let i = 0; i < minusButtons.length; i++) {
  plusButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function plusProduct() {
    inputFields[i].value++;
  });
}
```

```css
.plus-btn::before {
  content: "+";
}

.minus-btn::before {
  content: "-";
}
```

```html
<!-- Product #1 -->
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"></button>
  <input type="text" value="0" id="input" />
  <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button"></button>
</div>

<!-- Product #2 -->
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"></button>
  <input type="text" value="0" id="input" />
  <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button"></button>
</div>

<!-- Product #3 -->
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"></button>
  <input type="text" value="0" id="input" />
  <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button"></button>
</div>
```

Please note that your code also had useless, and worse, **duplicate** `id` values (which is not allowed in HTML). I removed those.

Answer (score 0):

Did some tidy up on the code, corrected ID to Class as cannot use duplicates ID.
Also added a listen for document load to ensure the code does not trigger before page ready. 
Changed away from querySelector as this only gets first element (could change back for the input method)

```js
//Cannot use querySelector, it only returns the first element
// NOTE: We have to pass in the button, this allows us to get 
// parent and limit the scope of our search.
const inputField = (button) => {
  return button.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('input')[0];
};

// use this initializer to ensure the document is ready for us
// to search and add our event listeners
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  setUpMinusButtons();
  setUpPlusButtons();
});

// Use a common method to assign our on clicks
function setUpButtons(buttonArr, eventAction) {
  for(let i=0; i<buttonArr.length; i++) {
    buttonArr[i].addEventListener('click', eventAction);
  }
}


function setUpMinusButtons() {
  let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('minus-btn');

  setUpButtons(buttons, 
    function minusProduct(event) {
      let button = event.target;
      let iField = inputField(button);
      const currentValue = Number(iField.value);
      if (currentValue > 0) {
        iField.value = currentValue - 1;
      } else currentValue = 0
    }); 
}

function setUpPlusButtons() {
  let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('plus-btn');

  setUpButtons(buttons, 
   function plusProduct(event) {
      let button = event.target;
      let iField = inputField(button);
      const currentValue = Number(iField.value);
      iField.value = currentValue + 1;
    }); 
}
```

```html
<!-- Product #1  CHANGED our ID to Class for buttons-->
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button" id="plus">
                 <img src="plus.svg" alt="" />
               </button>
  <input type="text" value="0" class="input">
  <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button" id="minus">
                 <img src="minus.svg" alt="" />
               </button>
</div>
<!-- Product #2 -->
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button" id="plus">
                 <img src="plus.svg" alt="" />
               </button>
  <input type="text" value="0" class="input">
  <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button" id="minus">
                 <img src="minus.svg" alt="" />
              </button>
</div>
<!-- Product #3 -->
<div class="quantity">
  <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button" id="plus">
                 <img src="plus.svg" alt="" />
               </button>
  <input type="text" value="0" class="input">
  <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button" id="minus">
                 <img src="minus.svg" alt="" />
               </button>
</div>
```